# Deploy a django app that allows user file downloads

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am new to django and I am building a site that allows people to download pdf files. I can upload files easily but I now need help in allowing users to download files. I have seen something like:

```
def document_view(request, document_id):
    document = Document.objects.get(id=document_id)
    response = HttpResponse()
    response.content = document.file.read()
    response["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename={0}".format(
            document.pretty_name)
    return response
```

html:

```
<a id="download" download="" href="">download</a>
```

and I hear it's not a good idea for production and it's slow. Nginx + uWSGI combination is recommended but I use a Windows machine and I am not comfortable moving to Linux. Is there another way to do this on Windows?